# How to access each element of an Array of Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I am creating a array of objects , called rooms.

`static Room [] rooms = new Room [3];`

```
//populate the array. 
rooms[0] = new Room ("Bedroom", "This is your bedroom." );
rooms[1] = new Room("Hallway", "This is the hallway of your house.");

//constructor
static String room = "";
static String descriptionOfTheRoom = "";
public Room ( String newRoom, String newDescriptionOfTheRoom  ){
        room = newRoom;
        descriptionOfTheRoom = newDescriptionOfTheRoom;
}

// get room method 
public String getRoom (){
        return room;
    }

// when I try to get the room. 
     System.out.println("Room" + r[i].getRoom() );
```

It prints me the room that was added last to array. So always prints Hallway.
So how can I print each element at the time? or access each element?

Thank you to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you made the `descriptionOfTheRoom` and the `room` variables `static`. They should be instance variables.

Unlike instance variables, `static` members are shared among all instance of a class. These members should almost never be set in a constructor (sometimes you may need to modify them, but that is not too common).

You should make `room` and `descriptionOfTheRoom` instance variables, i.e. one per `Room` object. Removing `static` will fix this problem.

Comment: I want to give you a hug. I have another array in the same project, and that was working fine because there is no static there . I have been messing with this thing for to long, cant see anymore . Thank you very much.